# Ordering integer numbers in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query like this

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_rights ORDER BY user_id DESC;
```

Why it gives me those messed up numbers?

```
USER_ID
4
4
4
4
3
3
21
21
21
21
21
21
20
20
```

It does not order the numbers as expected.

PROOF : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c753a/1

I understand that they may be ordered alphabetically or numerical, buy i don't understand why is this result so weird...

Comment: What is the data type of column user_id? and which database?

Comment: Well, your user_id is a `VARCHAR` so they **are** ordered alphabetically in descending order. When comparing `3` against `21`, the comparison can end after checking the first character (*3 > 2)*. If this is not what you had in mind, change the column type to a real number. *(or pad your numbers with zero's)*

Comment: i understand, it was my awareness again ... damn it!

Comment: @Empeus - don't sweat about it but just curious, why do you have an `ID` column declared as `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `user_id` is not numeric.

TRY this,

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_rights 
ORDER BY CAST(user_id as SIGNED) DESC;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c753a/13)

Another solution is to change the datatype of your column `user_id` to `int`

Comment: Or better, store the data properly. :)

Comment: i understand, it was my awareness again ... damn it! thank you

Comment: @MahmoudGamal where can you find the top user list per tag? honestly i don't know..all I know is Jon Skeet being the no 1..hehe

Comment: @MahmoudGamal thanks for the info, i didn't know that there was a also a top user list per tag until now :D

Answer (score 0):

Your userid field is a `varchar(64)`, so it is sorting it alphabetically, descending (as the SQL query requires). Given this, your output is exactly correct.

You should change your userid datatype, or cast it to an integer if you can guarantee it will always be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

hey if there are multiple entries of user in table than you can use group by and than try order by i.e.`SELECT user_id FROM user_rights GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY CONVERT(int,user_id) DESC;`